# Get an exception with Invalid reference from Solr DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory

Tags: solr

I am using solr 6.2. I am trying to configure multiple suggester definition in Solr search component and got error information like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'softId_suggest'
at org.apache.lucene.expressions.SimpleBindings.getValueSource(SimpleBindings.java:84)
at org.apache.lucene.expressions.ExpressionValueSource.<init>(ExpressionValueSource.java:45)
at org.apache.lucene.expressions.Expression.getValueSource(Expression.java:80)
at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory.fromExpression(DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory.java:107)
at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory.create(DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory.java:92)
at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester.build(SolrSuggester.java:174)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.buildSuggesterIndex(SuggestComponent.java:528)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.newSearcher(SuggestComponent.java:508)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$3(SolrCore.java:1863)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the config in my Solrconfig.xml is:

```
    <field name="softId_suggest" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"  />
<copyField source="softId" dest="softId_suggest" />
```

```
 <lst name="suggester">
   <str name="name">MySuggest</str>
   <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
   <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentExpressionDictionaryFactory</str>
   <str name="field">suggest_name</str>
   <str name="highlight">false</str>
   <str name="weightExpression">softId_suggest</str>       
   <str name="indexPath">analyzingInfixSuggesterIndexDir</str>
   <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
 </lst>
```

From the source of lucene I know that it seems that the field `softId_suggest` is null, but how to configure it to be right?

Comment: I am running into the same exact issue. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your description, you say that you configured softId_suggest in **solrconfig.xml**. But the fields are configured in **managed-schema** file. So, either that's the problem or you need to correct the question.

If it is defined correctly, make sure you've reloaded the core, rerun the import and committed.

Then, I would check Admin UI's Schema page and ensure that the field is both present in the dropdown and that it has some values loaded (*Load Term Info* button).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have corrected the question in configuration file and I can see that the field "softid_suggest" is in the Admin UI's Schema page,but the error informaion still display when I try to restart tomcat server.

Comment: Can you try that against the stock Solr configuration with minimal changes. You are talking about tomcat server, which is not supported in Solr 6.2. Maybe you got some deployment issues.

Answer (score 0):

resolution: set docValues to false in your schema for the field used by weightExpression in solrconfig.xml

```
<field name="weight" type="pdouble" docValues="false"/>
```

An easy way to verify that your field setting are correct is to set

```
<str name="weightExpression">(ln(weight))</str>
```

You may then get a different (more helpful!) error like

```
"Type mismatch: weight was indexed as SORTED_NUMERIC"
```

This is more familiar territory and we have pinpointed the problem. Simply **docValues=false** will fix this.